# Adding a string inbetween items in a ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have an ItemTemplate displaying items. My problem is I want to interject some "|" in between them. The problem I am having is if there is less than 3, there is no guarantee that the "|" won't end up at the end.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <div>
   <%# (Item.Item1 != null) ? "Item 1 |" : "" %>
   <%# (Item.Item2 != null) ? "Item 2 |" : "" %>
   <%# (Item.Item3 != null) ? "Item 3" : "" %>      
  </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The results I am looking for is something like:

Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3

Item 1

Item 2 | Item 3

As you can see the "|" won't be at the end of any possible scenario. Without adding a "|" inside the string above in a possible result, how do I make sure that the "|" doesn't end up at the end?

Comment: If you put the items in an Array or List, you could do `string.Join(" | ", MyList)`

Comment: Will try that thanks